# C++ - unable to read highest value in vector

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2015

I have a program which is retrieving stock market records from a txt file. I insert this file into a vector and it can successfully read the file without any issues. What I'm trying to do is retrieve the highest share price value.

This is my vector template:

```
#ifndef H_VectorTemplate
#define H_VectorTemplate

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class elemType>

class Vector
{
public:
//default constructor
Vector();

//specific constructor
Vector(int size);

//Destructor
virtual ~Vector();

//insert and print
void insert(const elemType& i);
void print() const;

elemType at(int i) const;

//for dealing with arrays

bool isEmpty() const;
bool isFull() const;

int size() const;

private:
elemType *list;
int length;
int maxsize;

};

//Implementation

template<class elemType>
bool Vector<elemType>::isEmpty() const
{
 return (length = 0);
}

template<class elemType>
bool Vector<elemType>::isFull() const
{
 return (length = 4000);    
}

template<class elemType>
void Vector<elemType>::print() const
{
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    cout << list[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
}

template<class elemType>
Vector<elemType>::Vector() //constructor
{
  maxsize = 200;
  length = 0;
 list = new elemType[maxsize];
}

template<class elemType>
Vector<elemType>::Vector(int size)
{
  if (size <= 0)
  {
    cout << "Invalid size, setting size to 200" << endl;
    maxsize = 200;
  }

 else
    maxsize = size;

length = 0;
list = new elemType[maxsize];
}

template<class elemType>
void Vector<elemType>::insert(const elemType& i)
{
 if (length == 4000)
    cout << "Cannot insert" << endl;
 else
 {
    list[length] = i;
    length++;
 }
}

template<class elemType>
Vector<elemType>::~Vector()
{
  delete []list;
}

template<class elemType>
elemType Vector<elemType>::at(int i) const
{
 return list[i];
}

template<class elemType>
int Vector<elemType>::size() const
{
  return length;
}

#endif
```

I'm using this method to point the location of a line in the vector:

```
 elemType Vector<elemType>::at(int i) const
 {
  return list[i];
 }
```

This is my main program:

```
int choice;
cout << "Please enter your choice: " << endl << endl;
cout << "1. Retrieve highest share price of the day" << endl;
cout << "2. Retrieve lowest share price of the day" << endl;
cout << "3. Generate output file" << endl;
cout << "Your choice: ";
cin >> choice;

if (choice == 1)
{
    cout << endl << "This is the highest bid of the day: " << endl;
    double HP = V1.at(0).getPrice();
    for (int i = 1; i < V1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (V1.at(i).getPrice() > HP)
        {
            HP = V1.at(i).getPrice();
        }
    }

    //Vector <Shares> HP1;
    for (int j = 0; j < V1.size(); j++)
    {
        if (V1.at(j).getPrice == HP)
        {
            cout << "Date and Time of transaction: " << V1.at(j).getDateTime;
            cout << "Highest price: " << V1.at(j).getPrice;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I am using overloading to print the values of the vector, so that is why it is working successfully.

[image]

Comment: `getDateTime` and `getPrice` are functions. You need to call them with parentheses: `getDateTime()` and `getPrice()`.

Comment: It's just a typo not worth a whole question..

Comment: Ah, my mistake sorry. I still get the '=' function as left operand error. I can't use '==' either. since it says no conversion from double to double.

Comment: @bumpfox "no conversion from double to double" - I bet it doesn't say that.

Comment: A little more than that. Here: http://i.imgur.com/PrKJRs7.png

Comment: off topic: `Vector<elemType>::Vector(int size)` you can remove the need for tests of negative numbers if you change `size`'s type from an `int` to an `unsigned int`

Comment: @bumpfox Exactly: you are trying to compare a `double` to a function that *returns* a `double`. You have to actually *call* the function. You are missing the parentheses: `()` in the function call.

Comment: Ah sorry, I changed it to if `(V1.at(j).getPrice() == HP)` and it works. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`length = 0` is wrong, use the equal to **==** operator

```
template<class elemType>
bool Vector<elemType>::isEmpty() const
{
 return (length == 0);
}
```

`length = 4000` is wrong, use the equal to **==** operator

```
template<class elemType>
bool Vector<elemType>::isFull() const
{
 return (length == 4000);    
}
```

`V1.at(j).getPrice == HP` is wrong: use getPrice() to call it

```
    if (V1.at(j).getPrice() == HP)
```

Comment: Good eyes. Didn't see those.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Also avoid hardcoding magical literals like `4000` right into the function, declare them elsewhere as constants or macros.